# show tables, too many rows to view on screen

Tags: mariadb

Im setting up a server, using mariadb
show tables in database has over 120 lines
With the last 60 rows showing on screen.
Im using terminal,no gui,ubuntu22.04
I dont have a scroll function , how do i view all the tables?
Is there a command to show tables alphabeticaly a through m then m through z
Or smaller  groups so i can read them.
In sections,
I know one of the tables has over 50k lines
How can i scroll through it all lin by line to make changes.

Comment: Please clarify your Post. It's unclear what your actual question is. Are you trying to view the names of all tables in your database or actually view all the rows of data that's inside those tables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For showing only some tables use the where condition in `show tables ... where ...`
For showing only part of the data in select statements use the `limit` clause in `select ... limit ...`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the commandline tool, enter the command

```
pager less
```

That will pause the output at a screenful.  Then use the spacebar to move to the next screenful, or `q` to "quit" paginating.  Establishaing a non-default pager will be in effect for all output (eg a big `SELECT`).  Cancel it with

```
pager
```

PS `LIMIT` does not work with all commands.; that is AlexM's Answer is incomplete.